# Browser navigation in SSRS subrapports using drillthrough action not working properly

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, ssrs-2012

Our browser navigation (forward, backward) does not function properly when performing a drillthrough action to a subrapport in SSRS rapports after a upgrade/migration.

We used to run SSRS in native mode (SQL Server 2008 R2) as a webpart in sharepoint 2010. We have migrated these reports for a sharepoint 2013 solution running on SQL Server 2012 using SSRS in Sharepoint integrated mode, and showing them as webparts through report viewer.

The problem is that after performing a drillthrough action in a report, hitting the browser back button sends you to the previous page you visited instead of sending you to the previous report. This was not the case before migration. Similarily hitting the forward button sends you back to the page you just left.

Comment: Some help would be very appreciated. We are still stuck on the same problem. This is an important feature  for the end-users.

Answer (score 0):

I have at times seen the need to create a "back" image with an action on the sub report to go to the last/parent report. Not sure if this is an option for you, but maybe.

You can send the name of a report as a parameter to the sub report so you know which report you are supposed to go back to when pushing the image. If you need to drill down more than one level you might need more "previous-report" parameters so you can keep some sort of history. This does not solve the "Forward" button though so that will still be a normal drill down.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunatly, this does not solve the problem. The users are using browser backbutton/backspace/mouseback.

Answer (score 0):

I've always been a bit suspicious of the webpart implementation for SSRS. I prefer to directly access the libraries, or use links or URLs to the report (rdl) documents.

This avoids your issue, and gives a cleaner "full page" experience.

Comment: I could do it, and I tried it. It does not fixx the backbutton problem. Running SSRS in native mode is not supported in SharePoint 2013 + SQL Server 2012, hence using a web-part is no different from running them in direct access library with SharePoint integrated mode.

Comment: What was supposed to be a straight forward migration+upgrade between versions of the same Microsoft software ended up in a nightmare...

Comment: I wasn't suggesting running SSRS in native mode. I was suggesting not using web parts.

Answer (score 0):

How about opening the Drill Through report in a new window instead of the same one? Then they couldn't hit back - just close the current window.

The tricky part is coding any parameters by hand instead of using the drop downs in the action.

Instead of using Jump to Report, you could use Jump to URL and put the full path and parameters in the URL address:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://servername/reportserver?%2fpathto%2freport&rs:Command=Render&ProductCode=" + Fields!ProductCode.Value + "'))"
```

This adds the ProductCode field as the parameter to a ProductCode parameter (your parameters may vary). You'd need to have Java running, though.
 I haven't tried this in SharePoint though.

Comment: This is a workaround that works, but unfortunately is just not good enough. The SSRS solution consist of over 150 reports, and you can navigate between them using drill-through action. Opening new tabs the whole time would first off be a lot of work to implement (lot of parameters to pass and having it work for all 150+ -> lot of javascripting to do), secondly I believe opening a lot of tabs while navigating will not be welcomed by the end user.